# Open Source program for converting wave files for RTMP streaming

Tags: streaming, converters, rtmp

Can anyone suggest any open source linux program for converting .wav files to flash format for RTMP streaming? Does RTMP support any format other than flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Media Server supports three audio formats for streaming: Nellymoser, MP3, and ACC.  You also can play MP3 files directly from the Flash Player view HTTP download, you don't really need to use RTMP (which is more advantageous for video due to higher bitrate).

Here's a good article on streaming audio with FMS:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/beginner_audio_fms3.html

For conversion, you can use ffmpeg.

http://fosswire.com/post/2007/11/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-to-mp3/

Comment: Thanks. I used ffmpeg. In case someone finds it useful, here is a site with all the conversion commands http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Answer (score 0):

You can stream via the [CRTMP server](http://rtmpd.com/) to flash clients. VLC can play RTMP streams.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a streaming server, but a program for converting wav files to a streamable format.